# Magento 2.3.4 - Error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode()

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, admin, magento2.3.4

I upgrade my store to Magento 2.3.4 version and suddenly I can't save / edit categories, after I press the Save button I have this error in admin: `Something went wrong while saving the category.` When I check `var/log/debug.log` file I found this error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on bool in /chroot/home/a593d01f/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php:67
```

and when I check

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php:67`

I have this part of code:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $category = $observer->getEvent()->getEntity();
    if (!$category->isObjectNew()) {
        foreach ($category->getDesignAttributes() as $designAttribute) {
            if ($this->isCategoryAttributeChanged($designAttribute->getAttributeCode(), $category)) {
                $this->cacheTypeList->invalidate(
                    [
                        \Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER,
                        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Layout::TYPE_IDENTIFIER
                    ]
                );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out this:

```
        if ($this->isCategoryAttributeChanged($designAttribute->getAttributeCode(), $category)) {
            $this->cacheTypeList->invalidate(
                [
                    \Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER,
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Layout::TYPE_IDENTIFIER
                ]
            );
            break;
        }
```

everything is work fine with categories. Is a magento bug? or how I can fix this?

**Edit:**

Theme dropdown attribute is empty, the name of this attribute is custom_design.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible ways to debug further.

**1. First try**

- Check If Flat catalog for category ENABLED then DISABLE it or if Flat Catalog for category found DISABLED then ENABLE it.
- Perform full reindexing
- Then try to save any category again, it should work.

**2.** 
If not solving then try to add the instance check condition like below:
Culprit attribute can be found by removing the comment in the first if condition.

```
    foreach ($category->getDesignAttributes() as $designAttribute) {
     if(!$designAttribute instanceOf \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute){
     //$designAttribute->getAttributeCode(); die('s');
     continue;
    }

        if ($this->isCategoryAttributeChanged($designAttribute->getAttributeCode(), $category)) {
            $this->cacheTypeList->invalidate(
                [
                    \Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER,
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Layout::TYPE_IDENTIFIER
                ]
            );
            break;
        }
 }
```

**3rd** thing you may try the last Review all the category attributes which are showing after executing the below query.

Compare with native Magento's instance table of the same `entity_type_id`.

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = 3
```

Comment: Hi thank you for you answer, unfortunately even if I try to uncomment that line to check what attribute missing or is broke I didn't find it. But I see something strange in the category in the Design tab,  the Theme field dropdown is empty, maybe this is the problem? Please check I update my post and I add a screenshot with that field ..

Answer (score 4):

In my case the attribute was not existed so I was needed to restore missed eav entities. Did it with \Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateCustomLayoutAttributes Data Patch

Just remove the installed state flag from patch_list and make setup:upgrade

Comment: thanks a lot, this was it!

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue after upgraded from Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.0. Categories cannot save and some products page do not work.

I solved this with the below simple steps:

1. Go to your Magento database and find `patch_list` table , find and delete `Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateCustomLayoutAttributes` value as below img
2. Run this command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and solve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem after updating from 2.3.4 to 2.3.4-p2, in my case, Custom Layout Update is empty.
The patch_list table does not contain Magento \ Catalog \ Setup \ Patch \ Data \ UpdateCustomLayoutAttributes, so I ran setup: upgrade but the table has not been updated and Custom Layout Update is still empty.
Any idea?

Comment: Adding the attribute will only solve the error in the admin. Because of safety reasons Magento moved away from allowing XML definitions being written in admin and saved in database.

Here is how its supposed to work in the later versions: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/layout-update-place-block.html

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem as well, because of a missing category attribute in the eav_attribute table. Try to run the query below. And if you are missing this attribute, you might be missing other attributes as well. Please compare the eav_attribute table in a new Magento 2 installation with your own to see if you are missing something.

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES

(4, 'custom_layout_update_file', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\LayoutUpdate', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'select', 'Custom Layout Update', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Source\\LayoutUpdate', 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL),
(3, 'custom_layout_update_file', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Attribute\\Backend\\LayoutUpdate', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'select', 'Custom Layout Update', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Attribute\\Source\\LayoutUpdate', 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: You are a saviour. +1

Comment: This allowed me to save however my custom layout update was still empty...

Answer (score 1):

In my case one attribute was deleted from database: **custom_layout_update_file**

I found it putting one breakpoint at:

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php

Line 67

Then i have removed the entry from patch from patch_list table.
After i've run bin/magento setup:upgrade and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution for this?

I am able to create a new category, but editing existing categories does not work, also unable to move the categories. I upgraded from Magento 1.9.x to  2.3.4 and have the same error message as yourself.

changing flat file catalog and re-indexing has not resolved it.

I will look at comparing the new category against the old one and see if I can see any difference between the database values.