# Updated to magento 2.3.5 doesn't let me change the Categories

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.3.5

I recently updated Magento 2 to v2.3.5 and the Categories have a problem.

If I click the **Save** button in any Category I receive this message [image: Categories error after Saved]

```
Argument 1 passed to
Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath() 
must be of the type String, array given, 
called in 
/home/adminpsol2016/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 167
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to above issue? I am getting same error after upgrade to Magento2.4.0.-p1

Comment: Hi everyone same issue I'm facing. please do share if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this via a plugin. This has happened after the upgrade of `Magento2.3.5` to `Magento 2.4` when we select multiple products using select all checkbox and save category.
Here is what I did -
Added `adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save">
    <plugin name="ControllerCategorySave" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CategoryPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
</config>
```

create plugin file called - `CategoryPlugin.php`

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
 
class CategoryPlugin
{        
    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save $subject)
    {
        $categoryPostData = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue();      
        
        $products = json_decode($categoryPostData['category_products'], true);
         if(in_array("on",$products))
        {
            array_pop($products);
        }   
        $newValue = json_encode($products); 
        $subject->getRequest()->setPostValue('category_products', $newValue);   
       
        return $subject;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete plugin code?

Comment: @Tejas Shah
we are getting an issue - 
undefined array key "category_products" in /var/www/html/xyz/app/code/Company/Vendor/Plugin/CategoryPlugin.php on line 10 [] []

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue after upgrading to 2.4.
For me the solution was to delete the \Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateCustomLayoutAttributes patch from the patch_list table

```sql
DELETE FROM 'patch_list' WHERE patch_name = 'Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateCustomLayoutAttributes'
```

Then run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Credit to: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307171/88690

Comment: correct query is 
delete FROM `patch_list` WHERE `patch_name` = 'Magento\\Catalog\\Setup\\Patch\\Data\\UpdateCustomLayoutAttributes'

Answer (score 0):

@Tejas Shah I have the same issue in Magento 2.4.3 but with your solution I get the notice:
Notice: Undefined index: category_products in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/mag2/app/code/Wrj/CategorySave/Plugin/CategoryPlugin.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

This comment in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33770#issuecomment-1133744546 fixed it for me.

While the error on the category page says Fileinfo.php, if I look into system.log I can see Duplicate entry errors as described in the github thread.