# I can't save a category in Magento 2.3.5-p2 - Probably after migration from 1.9.2

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.3.5-p2

I migrated a store from version 1.9.2 to 2.3.5-p2, I had some issues at first, as with any migration I did before, but I sorted everything out. The migration was made with the **official Magento migration tool.**

After a while of having the store online, I tried to enable / disable a category, or even only trying to save it without any change, and I'd always get this error:

**Something went wrong while saving the category.**

along with:

**Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath() must be of the type string, array given, called in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 167**

No error report is generated, and I can´t seem to find an issue on the debug, system or exception logs.

Everything else has been working fine, so I don´t know what the problem could be. So any help would be awesome.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I've found a "temporal solution" (I think). On this question:
[Magento 2.3.4 - Error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306773/magento-2-3-4-error-call-to-a-member-function-getattributecode)

On the file: ***vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php*** on line 67 I commented this part of code:

```
if ($this->isCategoryAttributeChanged($designAttribute->getAttributeCode(), $category)) {
            $this->cacheTypeList->invalidate(
                [
                    \Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER,
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Layout::TYPE_IDENTIFIER
                ]
            );
            break;
        }
```

And now I can edit my categories again. But I doubt that this is the right solution for this.

Comment: Hi, maybe something is wrong with category data? Verify this and try to save one more time. Perhaps delete unnecessary data?

Comment: What do you mean with the category data? For what I've looked through all day long, it's probably because of a custom attribute that existed before. But I have no clue on how to look for it.